# Make an iPhone appear as different model?

Tags: iphone, jailbreak

Is it possible to have a jailbroken iPhone trick an app into thinking you have a different device than the one you're on (e.g., a 3G passing as a 3GS)?

Comment: I closed [this same question previously](http://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/2926/make-a-jailbroken-3g-appear-as-3gs-to-app-closed) as too localized, but if anyone has an answer to it…

Comment: This time I changed it slightly, and made the question for any app, and for any device.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Palm did this with the Pre: the device, like all devices, told iTunes it was an iPod and allowed only the syncing of non-DRM content over the USB connection. As to how the iPhone sorts out what it is to tell iTunes could either be hard-coded or come from a `plist` file somewhere in the OS.

Either way, this forum is really not the place the find the answer to that question(nor do I think SO is either). You probably should head over to one of the myriad iPhone jailbreak forum. Searching "iPhone jailbreak forum" in Google brings up a whole host of them.

Comment: Oh so the Apple site is not the place to ask about an iPhone? Anyway it doesn't matter I got a new iPhone. But there 3 up votes on the question which suggest others also want to know.

Comment: I'm not saying that this SE site isn't the place to ask this question; it's about an Apple product so, technically, it's appropriate. I'm just saying that you'll probably have better luck actually getting an answer about iPhone hacking elsewhere, like in a forum dedicated to iPhone hacking. I know it's not a real answer to your question, but hard hacking questions like this don't get answered much here.